# pandas cumsum and start again

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a normal dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1,1,2,3,4,4,5], 'param': [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would like to create a new column and do cumsum and start again once after every second id like the following scheme:

[[image]

It starts with 1. Once a new value in column1 ('id) it should increase by one. Once again a new value in column 1 it should start 1 again and so on.

Comment: I can't understand exactly what you are trying to do - can you be more specific how the column is to be calculated?

Comment: Okay I try: It starts with 1. Once a new value in column1 ('id) it should increase by one. Once again a new value in column 1 it should start 1 again and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `id` column contains adjacent integers (as in the example), you could derive the `new_id` columns by looking at the least significant bit of `id`:

```
df["new_id"] = 2 - np.bitwise_and(1, df.id)
```

If `id`s are more general, you can call `groupby` + `ngroup` first, then reuse the above solution:

```
df["new_id"] = np.bitwise_and(1, df.groupby(df.id).ngroup()) + 1
```

Result:

```
   id  param  new_id
0   1     11       1
1   1     22       1
2   2     33       2
3   3     44       1
4   4     55       2
5   4     66       2
6   5     77       1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd almost have to solve this one by binning the data.  In this case I used `qcut` to create `len(df) // 2` bins - 3 in this case.

If you look at the results of the `qcut` you can see the group labels that get generated:

```
pd.qcut(df.id,len(df)//2)

0    (0.999, 2.0]
1    (0.999, 2.0]
2    (0.999, 2.0]
3      (2.0, 4.0]
4      (2.0, 4.0]
5      (2.0, 4.0]
6      (4.0, 5.0]
```

Using this as a groupby key, we can check whether each `id` within each group is not equal to the `id.shift`, which returns a boolean value which can be used for `cumsum`

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1,1,2,3,4,4,5], 'param': [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['new_id'] = df.groupby(pd.qcut(df.id,len(df)//2)).apply(lambda x: (x.id.ne(x.id.shift())).cumsum()).values
```

Output

```
   id  param  new_id
0   1     11       1
1   1     22       1
2   2     33       2
3   3     44       1
4   4     55       2
5   4     66       2
6   5     77       1
```

Comment: I get the following error: ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([1.00e+00, 1.00e+00, 1.00e+00, ..., 1.14e+03, 1.14e+03, 1.14e+03]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg. In fact my dataframe is quite long (20 000 000 rows). I tried to do duplicates='drop' but did not succeed. -.-

Comment: Okay I changed to df['new_id'] = df.groupby(pd.qcut(df.label_id.rank(method='first').values,len(df)//6), duplicates='drop').apply(lambda x: (x.label_id.ne(x.label_id.shift())).cumsum()).values but it is quite slowly :/

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach; seems to be about 3-4x faster.

```
2.2 ms ± 238 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
8.65 ms ± 884 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
df['new_id'] = df['id'].map(df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: 1).cumsum().add(1).mod(2).add(1).to_dict())

   id  param  new_id
0   1     11       1
1   1     22       1
2   2     33       2
3   3     44       1
4   4     55       2
5   4     66       2
6   5     77       1
```